# How can I change the hover color of tools in the UI?

Tags: interface, customization

How can I change the color or light intensity of tabs that are hovered over in blenders user interface?

For example if I hover over the translate option in the tools tab while in the 3d view, it changes color. How can I customize that color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that colour can be changed. The options for those colours are in *User Preferences> Themes> User Interface> Tool*.

The 'Inner' colour is the colour of the button and the 'Inner Selected' is the colour when pressed, but there is no colour for 'Inner Hover'. The hover colour seems to just calculated based on the 'Inner Colour'. If it is red then the hover colour is lighter red, if it is green the hover is lighter greet etc.

Comment: You are right, I guess to change what i want i would have to do some python programming. Nonetheless playing around in with the colors and gradients provided a temporary resolution, Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

In the user settings there is a "themes" tab. Use it to change any colors you see fit!

You can also look around - there are many color schemes to be had!

Comment: trust me i look long and hard, found nothing